# std::array::iterator that ignores the size template

Tags: c++, arrays, c++14, const-iterator

I am implementing a function that wants to loop over a number of elements in an std::array, but I don't really care how long the std::array is. So I was thinking of the following function:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <array>
#include <iterator>

void foo(std::array<bool,0>::const_iterator begin, std::array<bool,0>::const_iterator end)
{
    printf("iterator");
}

int main()
{
    std::array<bool, 25> one;
    std::array<bool, 33> two;

    foo(one.cbegin(), one.cend());
    foo(two.cbegin(), two.cend());
}
```

I am quite okay with this, except for the `std::array<bool,0>`. My question is, is there another way to specify the iterator that is required for this function?

---

**Update**

There are some things I should mention. Of course this code is part of a bigger scope and I tried to hide as much detail as I could.

1. I want to ensure that the iterator being used is of `bool`s.
2. I am using C++14
3. The function is part of a class interface and I want to be able to handle multiple array sizes. I don't want to bother the implementors of the interface to know exactly what the size of the array is.

```cpp
class MyInterface
{
public:
    virtual foo(std::array<bool,0>::const_iterator begin, std::array<bool,0>::const_iterator end) = 0;

    ~MyInterface() = default;
};
```

I remembered that virtual functions cannot be templated. That means I would have to template my whole interface and that would exactly loose the point of why I was trying this in the first place.

Comment: You could extract the array size as a template parameter to that function.

Comment: Do you want _the_ iterator for `std::array<bool, N>`, or _an_ iterator? Since `std::array<bool,N>` is contiguous, `bool*` is a valid iterator type for it.

Comment: @MSalters I am trying to use sort of modern approaches and not use simple types like bool pointers, although it might be the best solution for what I want to achieve. But I'm first looking for alternatives, therefore the question. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Marnix: "Modern approaches" means that we use smart pointers for `new bool` and `new bool[ ]`. It's still OK to use `bool*` as a non-owning pointer into a contiguous `bool[ ]`. It's not like we now use `std::pointer<bool>`, although there's `std::span<bool>` in C++20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just make it a function template as

```
template <typename I>
void foo(I begin, I end)
{
    std::cout << "iterator";
}
```

You don't need to care about container type (and the size), you can pass iterators of `std::array`, `std::vector` and `std::string` and so on, even raw pointers (which also satisfies iterator's requirements).

Comment: I come from a C# background and as far as I know I find it very satisfying to know what the container type is. Why is this something we can ignore?

Comment: @Marnix The great thing about this is that the interface is not unnecessarily constrained. It is more flexible to have an algorithm that works with any pair of iterators (possibly limited by iterator category) rather than just array iterators.

Comment: @Marnix In C++ iterators are independent concept; they're quite general. Then the function template becomes general too, it could work with any iterators from any containers. You might check function templates from algorithm library, they all accpet only iterators (but not containers).

Comment: I can agree on that. I updated my question. It seems that I missed out on something and that is the fact that the function itself is inside an interface. Therefore templating the function is not possible, since virtual functions cannot be templated. But also I don't want to template the interface, because I want the interface to be flexible.

Comment: @Marnix In that case see Ayxan's answer which does not require a template.

Comment: @Marnix AFAIK it's impossible without templates; there's no guarantee that the iterator type of all the instantiations of `std::array` are the same. E.g. `std::array<bool, 25>::iterator` and `std::array<bool, 0>::iterator` might be different types, then we can't make an interface for it without templates.

Comment: @Marnix: "*I don't want to template the interface, because I want the interface to be flexible.*" Templating the interface is *how* we make things flexible in C++. Different language, different rules. As for "*Why is this something we can ignore?*", you can ignore it because ignoring the container is the entire point of iterators. They abstract access to containers so that you don't have to care what container the iterator comes from.

Comment: @songyuanyao Interesting. I thought that the iterator would be exactly the same. Perhaps just a pointer and the size of the array is the way to go then.

Comment: @Marnix I checked with gcc and clang, the types seem to be the same; but in [MSVC](https://rextester.com/GLNKTQ71568) they're not. As MSalters suggested a `bool*` might be a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `span`:

```
#include <array>
#include <span>

class MyInterface {
public:
    virtual void foo(std::span<bool> barr) = 0;

    // interface destructors should be virtual
    virtual ~MyInterface() = default;
};

void bar(MyInterface& interface) {
    std::array<bool, 42> arr;
    interface.foo(arr);
}
```

If you don't have access to a C++20 compiler, you may use [`gsl::span`](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/span) from [gsl](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use a template:

```
template <size_t N>
void foo(std::array<bool,N>::const_iterator begin, std::array<bool,N>::const_iterator end)
{
    printf("iterator");
}
```

And now as long as both iterators come from an array of size `N` this function will work.

---

If you want to accept iterators from different sized arrays, you just need to add another template parameter for the second iterator like

```
template <size_t N, size_t M>
void foo(std::array<bool,N>::const_iterator begin, std::array<bool,M>::const_iterator end)
{
    printf("iterator");
}
```

Comment: IINM there's no point in having two parameters, as the two iterators have to point into the same container.

Comment: @Quentin In this case I agree.  It was more for others that find this Q&A and might need to accept iterators to different sized arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If the function accepts two iterators when the referring std::array is redundant. Just declare the function like

```
template <class Iterator>
void foo( Iterator first, Iterator last );
```

In the declaration you can name the iterator that corresponds to the used iterator type in the function like for example

```
template <class ForwardIterator>
void foo( ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last );
```

Or instead of the name `ForwardIterator` you could use the name `BidirectionalIterator` or `RandomAccessIterator` for self-documenting.

If you need to know the value type of the iterator you can use different approaches. For example

```
template <class Iterator>
void foo( Iterator first, Iterator last )
{
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;
    if ( first != last )
    {
         value_type item1 = *first;
         // or
         auto item2 = *first;
         //
         const auto &item3 = *first;
         //...             
    }
}
```

In this case you will have a flexible function definition. For example if in future you will change `std::array<N, bool>` to `std::vector<bool>` the function will as usual work.